# Quadcopter Stability Modelling

Tags: quadcopters, stability

We know software like XFLR5 to model fixed-wing aircraft to determine aircraft dynamics and stability. Is there any software which we can model our quadcopter geometry in so we can know it's CoG, thrust, lift, stability, etc?

Comment: CoG can be determined in CAD suites if your program in the density/mass of all of the parts and materials.

Answer (score 3):

Solidworks works great and is very intuitive for beginners for a CAD software. Given that you have the entire simulation suite it can perform stress analysis and automatic optimization for the frame, air flow simulation for the propellers, etc etc (nice video to start with here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6y_G6om74Mc). If you want to go deeper in the analysis of a custom flight controller, then you should investigate solutions through Matlab - a bunch of mechatronics students have produced a lot on the subject and you can buy drone focused video courses like this one to get up to speed: "Model, Simulate and Control a Drone in MATLAB & SIMULINK" on Udemy.

But unfortunately I'm yet unaware of a dedicated piece of software to do all this; my approach is to use engineering "general purpose" CAD softwares and model everything because I've learned these tools at work.